# attachInterrupt for mega 2560 not triggering

Tags: button, input, atmega2560

I recently bought a mega 2560 to toy around with as a hobby. It's pretty fun so far, but I've recently gotten stuck while trying to use attachInterrupt with a button. I'm using the CHANGE mode, and have read the documentation pretty thoroughly ( I think ).

I've looked up multiple questions and tried to fix my setup and I still can't seem to make it work.

Here's my code:

```
int buttonPin = 18;
int ledPin1 = 11;
int ledPin2 = 9;
int ledPin3 = 5;

int value = 0;

void setup() {
  //declare inputs and outputs
  pinMode(buttonPin,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(ledPin1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin3,OUTPUT);

  //create interrupt for button
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(5),count,CHANGE);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  if(value == 0){ digitalWrite(ledPin1,HIGH);}
  else{ digitalWrite(ledPin1,LOW); }

  if(value == 1){ digitalWrite(ledPin2,HIGH);}
  else{ digitalWrite(ledPin2,LOW); }

  if(value == 2){ digitalWrite(ledPin3,HIGH);}  
  else{ digitalWrite(ledPin3,LOW); }

  delay(500);
  Serial.print(digitalRead(buttonPin));

}

//count occurs when button is pressed
void count(){
  //incremement a counter
  value++;
  //reset counter from 3 to 0
  if(value >= 2){ value = 0; }
}
```

It's a pretty simple sketch. I'd attach a picture of my current setup but I don't really think It's needed. The button is indeed working as I'm debugging using serial.print().

If not clear, the objective of the sketch is to change the LED lit when the button is pressed. Currently, the variable value is stuck at 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> //create interrupt for button
> attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(5),count,CHANGE);
> ```

The code does not match the comment.

```
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonPin),count,CHANGE);
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't quite make sense to me though, the documentation for attachInterrupt says I should use 5 instead of 18... https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/

Comment: I'd like to upvote your answer but I'm not high enough in reputation

Comment: It says *if* you are going to use the interrupt number instead, that you should use 5. But then you wouldn't use `digitalPinToInterrupt()`, since that is already the interrupt number. It also recommends that you *don't* use the interrupt number.

Comment: Silly mistake for me to make. Thanks again for the help!